# Compiling requires to #include "stdafx.h"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I just started using Visual Studio 2013. My code would not compile until I started to put #include "stdafx.h" at the beginning of every cpp file. Will this cause any problems when other people go to compile my code through the Linux terminal? If I simply remove #include "stdafx.h" from the following code, would it compile C++11 with g++?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl; using std::cin;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "This is an awesome game to play with your friends!"
        << endl << "You have to pick an integer between 10 and 49 and type it in"
        << endl << "Then your friend has to pick an integer between 50 and 99 and type it in."
        << endl << "Through a series of highly advanced calculations starting with their number,"
        << endl << "They regenerate your original number. Have fun!"
        << endl << ""
        << endl << "Please enter your integer number, between 10 and 49:";


    int your_int, their_int, factor, sum, calculation, result;

    cin >> your_int;
    factor = 99 - your_int;
    cout << "Factor: " << factor
        << endl << "Now, please enter your friend's integer number between 50 and 99:";
    cin >> their_int;
    sum = factor + their_int;
    calculation = sum / 100 + sum % 100;
    result = their_int - calculation;
    cout << "The sum is: " << sum
        << endl << "The calculation is : " << calculation
        << endl << "The result is :" << result
        << endl << "My answer was: " << your_int
        << endl << "Your result was: " << result;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That depends entirely on the contents of `stdafx.h`. What happens when you try it? And what were the error messages before you added the include?

Comment: My instructors compile with g++ using Linux. I've been having issues with Linux on my P.C. so I've been using Visual Studio 2013. I

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Precompiled headers: what are they?

There seem to be some misconceptions about `stdafx.h` here. First off, it's just a header file and neither its contents nor its name are special in any way (see below).

When using precompiled headers in Visual Studio it by default uses `stdafx.h` and `stdafx.cpp` to accomplish this.

Precompiled headers are a way to speed up compilation, by 'pre-compiling' often used and rarely changed headers into a package; this package then can then be used when compiling every file in the project. It mostly contains definitions of various sorts.

To be able to use precompiled headers, for language-technical reasons, this needs to be the first piece of code in every source file. Therefore, when you use precompiled headers, the first code line of every source file must be the inclusion of this shared header. If this was not the case, a preprocessor macro definition before the header could radically change the way include files are parsed and thus 'invalidate' the precompiled header.

Now back to Visual Studio, all the headers and definition you want to share between all your files (for instance `windows.h`, STL headers, etc.) you include in `stdafx.h`. `stdafx.cpp` is just a helper file for the compiler which it uses to actually generate the pch files; you as a user never touch this file.

### Answer to your question

Now to answer your question:

**Option 1** As long as you stick to the C++11 standard and use portable code, in `stdafx.h` and everywhere else, there is no issue with including it as the first header everywhere.
When you use Visual Studio, you can then make use of precompiled headers, and any Linux environment will see it as just another header.
In fact, other compilers feature precompiled headers as well and they will directly be able to use `stdafx.h`, when the correct build flags are supplied.

**Option 2** You can disable precompiled headers in the project property sheet, under C/C++, Precompiled Headers, you can set Precompiled Header from Use to Not Using Precompiled Headers. Don't forget to do this for both the Debug and Release configuration. With this option turned off, you are no longer required to add `stdafx.h` to any file. I have found that IntelliSense works best when precompiled headers are used, so for this reason I usually prefer to keep them even for small projects.

### Additional information on `stdafx.h`

As mentioned, `stdafx.h` is not special. The Visual Studio project page, C/C++, Precompiled Headers, says which filename to use as a precompiled header. The file `stdafx.cpp` has a special property page that is different from the rest of the files on this subject. It's the only file that has Precompiled Headers set to Create rather than Use, so that's how the compiler knows which is the helper file.

It's perfectly possible to use different names or even multiple precompiled headers; all it requires is some additional configuration in the property pages.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. It's funny, because you offered me help for free than my instructors have at $400 a credit hour...lol. For whatever reason, my TA said that stdafx.h header file is not in g++. So, you will get a compilation error saying "No such file or directory".  With that being said, I think I will go with option 2. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. If you go with option 1, of course you have to copy `stdafx.h` with your other code files, just as you would any other file. It really is just a normal header file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `#include "stdafx.h"` will cause problems for anyone trying to compile your code on a Linux system.

`stdafx.h` is a non-standard header provided by Visual Studio.  It contains `#include` directives for several other standard headers.  The idea, I suppose, is to avoid having to type the standard header names.

Linux systems do not provide such a header.

If you want your code to be portable, you'll need to find out which standard headers to include in your program.

Without seeing your program, it's impossible to tell which headers you'll need.

You could write your own `"stdafx.h"` file, or copy the version generated by Visual Studio, but there's not much point in doing so. It's better, IMHO, just to include the standard headers you need directly.

Comment: stdafx.h is just the default precompiled header name, and it's empty by default. There's nothing more special about it, you can just as well disable its usage altogether.

Comment: It is just a plain .h file, it does not contain anything "non-standard" when you write cross-platform C++ code.

Comment: @HansPassant: Ok, but the existence of the file itself is non-standard. It imposes a particular coding style (wrapping standard headers in a single implementation-created `.h` file) that is perfectly usable on Linux, but IMHO poor style.

Comment: G++ and Clang also support precompiled headers, they work the exact same way. When everybody encourages "poor style" the same way to dramatically speed-up compilation time then there's something seriously wrong with the style.